# Does Javascript Events affect the the normal process flow in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to import a jQuery function into a into a webpage but i want those functions to run asychronously of the php controller.
Say a user clicks on a button, i want the php codes to get triggered first before thr javascript functions are executed.
How possible is this?

Do i just add the javascript file at the bottom of the page or something.

The javascript function makes API calls and i dont what it to interfere with the speed of the webpage.

Does the Async Method in HTML help?

Any advise would be welcome. Ask for clarification in comments, thanks.

Comment: IIRC, PHP is serverside, so any php code will have been ran on the server before your javascript is even loaded.

Comment: @Shilly so if there is a button that is used to book flights and runs lots of php codes backend, and there is an onclick() method on the button that makes an api call. you're saying the controller would run first and load the next page before the jquery onclick event is registered

Comment: Depends on how both are programmed. But if you get in this kind of situation, the problem will probably be your control flow. Are the page redicrect and the API call in any way dependant on eachother?

Comment: @Shilly no they are not related,... they can run independent of one another

Comment: You probably want to run the onclick handler first then and manually redirect to the php page in a callback or deferred function. How does the page redirect? a-tag? window.location? other? Show us some code so we understand what you're dealing with.

Comment: from what i understand the problem is that you think your javascript will make your page slower.That can be true it can make your page slower but that has nothing to do with PHP since PHP has already executed and produced your page (html and javascript).So if you worry for your page load that is another matter and generally yes is better to put javascript in the end of the page so loading javascript doesnt slow down html rendering

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `$.ajax` for this? That way the PHP code would be executed first, and you could call whatever javascript functions you wanted to in the `success` callback?

[Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Yea, that was what i eventually did, but i avoided the success callback because i dont want/need a response